# Using { in a table as if it were a vertical line

Tags: tables, brackets

The question is simple but I am afraid the answer is not: I would like to change the default vertical line between two columns of a table by a { as long as the vertical height of the table.

```
\begin{tabular}{l\{l}
```

That obviously, does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the bigdelim package.

Comment: Are both columns the same vertical length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

  \begin{blockarray}{l\{ l}
      Industria Virtutem parit: &
      Virtus Laudem excibat: \\
      Laus adfert honorem: & 
      Honoris socia est, \\
      Blah blah & blih blih\\
      Blah blah & blih blih
  \end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh 's excellent suggestion of using the `\Left{}{}` command produces a better spacing: the following code

```
 \begin{blockarray}{l \Left{}{\{\thinspace} l}
      Industria Virtutem parit: &
      Virtus Laudem excibat: \\
      Laus adfert honorem: &
      Honoris socia est, \\
      Blah blah & blih blih\\
      Blah blah & blih blih
  \end{blockarray}
```

yields
[image]

Comment: The answer is technically correct. However, I think it would be better to include `l \Left{}{\lbrace\thinspace}l` in the preamble of the `blockarray` instead of `l\{ l`. This is because it becomes easier to identify unequal opened and closed parentheses

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh. I've incorporated your fine suggestion. B.t.w., did you try this preamble `{l !{\{} l}`?

Comment: Such preamble inserts `\lbrace` before every two entries in the `blockarray` (it maintains the original spacing between columns). I read such a useful note in The LaTeX Companion

Comment: Really? When I tried with this code, I obtained a brace before each entry of the second column.

Comment: Yes, this is what I got. I just did not express what I wanted to say correctly